# Create a video game-like dialogue box that displays formatted text letter by letter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, pygame

Using **Python 2.7**, pygame, curses and Tkinter, I want to create a window that displays "animated" text, outputting it letter by letter from a list of strings.

I already got it working in console but I can't figure out how to tell the window that I want it to display the text letter by letter from the list of strings, rather than just giving it a static string to display.

Following is the code that generates the **"animated"** text

```
    for text in dialogue:
    window.clear()
    x,y = 0,1
    debug = True

    odd = False
    for letter in text:
        odd = not odd
        if letter not in ' |#$%':
            add(y, x, letter)
            if odd:
                sound.play_sound('blip')
```

And this is the function called above:

```
def add(y,x,c):
try:
    window.addstr(y, x, c)
    window.refresh()
except:
    return
```

Lastly, this is the block of code that generates and summons the window, which currently just displays some static text:

```
window1 = Tkinter.Tk()
window1.geometry("600x300")
window1.title = "Hengoku's Speech"
label = Tkinter.Label(ventana, text = dialogue, font = "Helvetica", bg = "#2A5545")
label.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expand = True)

window1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

A label can not animate text, only display static text (or image). But you can change the text in the label for every time you want to display the next text:

```
label.config(text=new_text)
```